# How do I redirect a page in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

How what data should I echo from the server to ajaxically redirect my page? Say, suppose this my jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : '<?php echo base_url() ?>Admin/AddNotice',
            data: {noticeTitle: $('#title').val(),noticeDesc : $('#desc').val() },
            success: function(msg){
                //here i want to redirect..fill in the blank please.
            }
        });
```

Comment: "ajaxically" is my new favorite word.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's pretty easy:

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com";
```

;)

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
success: function(msg){
  window.location = "page.html";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what you mean by "ajaxically redirect", but if you simply want the browser to redirect to another page, you can use `window.location = 'http://wherever/you/want/to/go/';`