# Page redirect with successful Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect

I have a form that uses Ajax for client-side verification. The end of the form is the following:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'mail3.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'contactName=' + name + '&contactEmail=' + email + '&spam=' + spam,

        success: function(result) {
            //console.log(result);
            $('#results,#errors').remove();
            $('#contactWrapper').append('<p id="results">' + result + '</p>');
            $('#loading').fadeOut(500, function() {
                $(this).remove();

            });

        }
    });
```

EDIT: this is my mail3.php file dealing with errors:

```
$errors=null; 

if ( ($name == "Name") ) {
    $errors = $nameError; // no name entered
}
if ( ($email == "E-mail address") ) {
    $errors .= $emailError; // no email address entered
}
if ( !(preg_match($match,$email)) ) {
    $errors .= $invalidEmailError; // checks validity of email
}
if ( $spam != "10" ) {
    $errors .= $spamError; // spam error
}

if ( !($errors) ) {
    mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    //header ("Location: thankyou.html");
    echo "Your message was successfully sent!";
    //instead of echoing this message, I want a page redirect to thankyou.html

} else {
    echo "<p id='errors'>";
    echo $errors;
    echo "</p>";
}
```

I was wondering if it's possible to redirect the user to a Thank You page if the ajax request is successful and no errors are present. Is this possible?

Thanks!
Amit

Comment: duplcate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430877/how-do-i-redirect-a-page-jquery

Comment: @Andrea: It's not a duplicate because I'm trying to redirect the page only if no errors are present. If errors are present, I want it to write those errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect a page in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430877/how-do-i-redirect-a-page-in-jquery)

Comment: I say it is a duplicate. The essence of question is how to redirect, and one can see in the linked Q&A, code that you can use here, after testing whatever you need to test to determine there are no errors. In fact, every answer *here* is just like the answers *there*, after the obvious "if" check.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Sure. Just put something at the the end of your success function like:

```
if(result === "no_errors") location.href = "http://www.example.com/ThankYou.html"
```

where your server returns the response `no_errors` when there are no errors present.

Comment: Proper usage of HTTP Status Codes will make every success a success without the server having to pass back any messages.

Comment: @Jeremy- True, unless you wanted to pass back specific error messages for the site to deal with or even different URLs to redirect to on failure. Those messages would have to be returned with a 200 response code necessitating a no_errors response to differentiate.

Comment: Actually from first look it would seem to me that this method would work!

Comment: Is it possible to GET the $error variable returned from the mail3.php file (see EDIT) and check for its content. if !($error), then redirect page?

Comment: @Adam - Not necessarily. The error function in jQuery's Ajax object will still have access to the response text of the response.

Answer (score 21):

Just do some error checking, and if everything passes then set `window.location` to redirect the user to a different page.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'mail3.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'contactName=' + name + '&contactEmail=' + email + '&spam=' + spam,

    success: function(result) {
        //console.log(result);
        $('#results,#errors').remove();
        $('#contactWrapper').append('<p id="results">' + result + '</p>');
        $('#loading').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).remove();

        });

        if ( /*no errors*/ ) {
            window.location='thank-you.html'
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: How can I check for no errors condition if all of the errors are processed through the mail3.php file?

Comment: you should trap errors in your mail3.php file, and return a status code of 500 on your response.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? How exactly do I return this status code of 500?

Comment: Is it possible to GET the $error variable returned from the mail3.php file (see EDIT) and check for its content. if !($error), then redirect page

Comment: @Amit I would do something like if(result === "Your message was successfully sent!")//redirect else $('#id ofEmptyDivOnPage').html(response) that'll display the errors on the page if there are errors and redirect if not assuming you have a div with that id

Comment: @Adam: Should the redirect using window.location work on a locally hosted server (using xampp)? Cuz it's not working

Answer (score 15):

You can just redirect in your `success` handler, like this:

```
window.location.href = "thankyou.php";
```

Or since you're displaying results, wait a few seconds, for example this would wait 2 seconds:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.href = "thankyou.php";
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Could you take a look at my edit to see how I can deal with the no error scenario? I only want it to be redirect to thankyou.php if no errors are present.

Comment: @Amit - You could put `if(result === "Your message was successfully sent!")` before this, that would only send in those cases.

Answer (score 3):

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'mail3.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'contactName=' + name + '&contactEmail=' + email + '&spam=' + spam,

        success: function(result) {

            //console.log(result);
            $('#results,#errors').remove();
            $('#contactWrapper').append('<p id="results">' + result + '</p>');
            $('#loading').fadeOut(500, function() {
                $(this).remove();

            });

            if(result === "no_errors") location.href = "http://www.example.com/ThankYou.html"

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

In your mail3.php file you should trap errors in a try {} catch {}

```
try {
    /*code here for email*/
} catch (Exception $e) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
}
```

Then in your `success` call you wont have to worry about your errors, because it will never return as a success.

and you can use: `window.location.href = "thankyou.php";` inside your success function like Nick stated.

Answer (score 2):

I posted the exact situation on a different thread. Re-post.

Excuse me, This is not an answer to the question posted above.

But brings an interesting topic --- WHEN to use AJAX and when NOT to use AJAX. In this case it's good not to use AJAX.

Let's take a simple example of login and password. If the login and/or password does not match it WOULD be nice to use AJAX to report back a simple message saying "Login Incorrect". But if the login and password IS correct, why would I have to callback an AJAX function to redirect to the user page?

In a case like, this I think it would be just nice to use a simple Form SUBMIT. And if the login fails, redirect to Relogin.php which looks same as the Login.php with a GET  message in the url like Relogin.php?error=InvalidLogin... something like that...

Just my 2 cents. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do that with:

```
window.location = "your_url";
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could attack this in two ways;

1) insert `window.location = 'http://www.yourdomain.com` into the success function.

2) Use a further ajax call an inject this into an element on your page, further info on which you can find in the jQuery docs at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 0):

Another option is:

```
window.location.replace("your_url")
```