# unable to redirect after successfully inserted data into mysql via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I use ajax, php to insert data into mysql database. However after finished executing all queries, it doesn't do anything. I mean, when I click submit button in the form, as a user I don't see anything happening even though I set my Ajax function to alert the data. But in the backend all data are inserted properly into the database.

So, I'm not sure how to notify user of a successful form submission. Could anyone help please? Thank you in advance.

I referred here, but it doesn't help:[Page redirect with successful Ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513971/page-redirect-with-successful-ajax-request)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script>
            var xmlhttp = false;
            try
            {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject(Msxml2.XMLHTTP);
                //alert("javascript version greater than 5!");
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                try
                {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject(Microsoft.XMLHTTP);
                   // alert("you're using IE!");
                }
                catch(E)
                {
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    //alert("non IE!");
                }
            }
```

> //Ajax function for some other element before submitting form

```
           function sendtobox(param,param2)
            {
              xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
              if (this.responseText !== null) {
                var ajaxElm = document.getElementById('boxA');
                ajaxElm.innerHTML = this.responseText + ajaxElm.innerHTML; // append in front
               }

             }
            }

                 xmlhttp.open("GET","getsubjects.php?q="+param+"&r="+param2,true);
                 xmlhttp.send();

            }
```

> //Ajax after submit button clicked

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  $(".form").submit(function(){
    var data = {
      "action": "test"
    };
    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "response.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        $(".the-return").html("<br />JSON: " + data["json"] );
        //alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
         window.location='tutor-profile.php'
        //header('Location:tutor-profile.php');
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

response.php

```
if (is_ajax()) {
  if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { //Checks if action value exists
    $action = $_POST["action"];
    switch($action) { //Switch case for value of action
      case "test": test_function(); break;
    }
  }
}

//Function to check if the request is an AJAX request
function is_ajax() {
  return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

function test_function(){

include('inc/config.php');
   $return = $_POST;
  //$return ='{"slider1":"150","level":{"Upper Secondary":"2"},"sub":{"8":""},"rate2":{"7":"89","8":"150","9":"150","10":"150","11":"150","12":"150","13":"150","14":"150"},"a_end":"on","e_week":"on","e_end":"on","name":"ting1","phone":"098-098-0980","email":"ting1@Gmail.com","postcode":"56547","gender":"on","password":"nk","action":"test"}';
  $return["json"] = json_encode($return);
  // json_encode($return);
  //  
  //below code to store in database 
  $data = json_decode($return["json"], true);
  //var_dump($data);        // Dump all data of the Array
  >>>>>>INSERT QUERIES GO HERE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
echo"form submitted ";
}
```

Comment: your response.php has to return the json data : `echo $data` not `echo form submitted`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code for redirect to another page in Javascript is

```
window.location.href ='tutor-profile.php'
```

Anyway they do not understand your previous roles and XMLHttpRequest your statements, that is ajax, but you simplify everything using only the last function $.ajax of jQuery.

The other correction is that you're saying that the server response will be of type "Json" but you just give back a string through a miss. What you can do is change it to this:

```
exit( json_encode( array('response'=>'put your text here') ) );
```

And then in JS instead of

```
$(".the-return").html("<br />JSON: " + data["json"] );
```

place this:

```
$(".the-return").html("<br />JSON: " + data.response );
```