# Handling Laravel Ajax Session Timeout Redirects in Handler

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

When the session timeouts, and I try to fire an ajax call on the same page where i had left initially, I am properly catching the TokenMismatchException and redirecting it to the login page. Now the issue is, the redirects happen internally and not visually. If the developer tools in chrome are open, I can see that the control or route shifts to the login page, but is not visible on the page, it still remains the same old page where it was left. On manual reload of page or when any link is clicked, the page visibly goes to the login page and says session timeout. How should I do redirects for AJAX globally in the Handler.php?

```
if($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException){
  return redirect('/login')->with('alert_error','Session Expired! Login to continue');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Postman` and disable `Automatically follow redirects` in settings to see what exactly happens.

Comment: I am not looking for an API call. Postman would help me in getting the response only. Here I am manually passing the control to log in. I cannot to that in Postman.What i want to know is that, is it usual behaviour not to load the page in case of an ajax session timeout occurs if catched in the Handler.php?

Comment: I think the ajax call follows the redirect and return the login page. If you want redirect the browser, try window.location. Like this: [Page redirect with successful Ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513971/page-redirect-with-successful-ajax-request )

Comment: I would appreciate your logic, its very true, that the above method will work, but the only issue is, I need to include it in all ajax calls throughout my project. Looking for one global place, where it can execute for ajax calls, though Handler.php would have been a great place to execute code, but window.location won't be helpful in the PHP script file.

Comment: Use Laravel auth middleware, check session and make the redirect.

Comment: I think its not necessary to redirect user on ajax calls. We can just return a message that notify user his authentication is expired. When user take an action(refresh, click button, post data),  it's time we redirect them to the login page.

Comment: Middleware doesn't trigger first when the session expires. It is directly an exception that is handled by the Handler.php. I cannot redirect in Middleware. As you can see in my above code, I am already passing the message in the return, but it doesn't show up on the actual page, though it shows up in the developer tools XHR Preview with the login page redirected. Thanks anyway for your time.