# How to pass JS data from script file to C# method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, function

I've been wracking my brain over this problem for a while. How can I invoke a JS function and retrieve the data to be used within a C# method?

Should I be using ViewBag in this example?

> .cshtml

```
<script>
  function somefunction(str)
   {
      //use str within Index() method
      return str;
   }
</script>
```

> Controller

```
   public IActionResult Index()
        {
            //use the data within this method
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: You either do a GET from the controller (passing the data up to the controller via the query string associated with the request) or you do a POST to the controller (typically you'd put the data in a JSON object, passed up to the controller as part of the request). The http request-response pattern has the client making the request and the server responding

Comment: To get something from `JS` to `C#` you need a network request. `JS` is living its own life on client side, while `C#` is on server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this

In javascript function:

```
//Do your action
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", new { value = 1})';
```

and modify the Index Action to accept parameter like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int value)
```

As your Index returns a View, window.location.href will basically redirect to Index action.

You can also create an url using string concatenation in javascript and use that url to redirect.

In my case the @Url.Action converts to this URL : '/Home/Index?value=1'.

Comment: There is also AJAX for this

Comment: If you found the solution that's great :) . If not take a look at this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513971/page-redirect-with-successful-ajax-request  ..

Comment: @DikeshKumar thank you so much for the answer. Your first suggestion has helped me!