# Google app engine with ajax request and python interactions

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, google-app-engine

Can anyone help me out of this problem, my javascript has an ajax GET Http request:

```
    $.ajax({
     url:"/testPage",
     type:'GET',
     success: function(){ 
        alert("done");
     }
 });
```

the server end python app has a handler to handle the Http request from js:

```
class testPageHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
       path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(_file_).'page1.html')
       template_values={}
       self.response.out.write(template.render(path,template_values))
  def post(self):
      .....
 application=webapp.WSGIApplication([('/testPage',testPageHandler),
      .....
```

In "get" method, I would like the Django template "page1.html" gets rendered, so the browser displays "page1.html" page, rather than just pops up "done".
any idea? thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a statement, not a question.

Comment: sorry i was editing up the question, you were just a bit earlier.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430877/how-do-i-redirect-a-page-jquery

Comment: not at all, i want the page1.html to be displayed rather than just a popup "done".

Comment: In your question you state you want to **redirect** the browser. How this can be done can be found in the question I linked to. If you want to dynamically add the response to the current page, then append it to an element in the page. How you append HTML to elements is described in the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/append/. In both cases you would of course use that code *instead* of the `alert`.

Comment: Hi Felix can your solution render a Django template "page1.html"(to be done in jQuery)? I am not sure if I missed something from the given links.

Comment: What's the point of using Ajax at all if you want to redirect on submit? That's how normal form submissions work anyway.

Comment: sorry I just updated the last two lines in my question hopefully it makes more sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django template is actually rendered and returned as response body. Now you just want to process it on client side.

```js
$.ajax({
    url:"/testPage",
    type:'GET',
    success: function(html){ 
        $('body').append(html);
    }
});
```

You can manipulate the response in whatever way you like. In the example above it is just appended to the `body` tag.

Comment: excellent answer,I didn't know the rendered template can be the response from the server to the ajax request. this also clarifies some details that I couldn't understand in Felix's comments.thank you Maxim.